# Is there a ContinueWith for ValueTask?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, valuetask

If an API returns a `ValueTask` or `ValueTask<T>`, is there a way to perform a `ContinueWith` on it, like I'm able to do with `Task`? Is there a Microsoft-provided NuGet library for doing so with .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: `ContinueWith` is the legacy API. Frankly, you shouldn't be using it **at all**. You should `await` both tasks and value-tasks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`valueTask.AsTask()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.astask). `AsTask()` is an escape hatch for just such use cases as yours. The purpose of `ValueTask` is to avoid allocations whenever possible, but if you're going to invoke a continuation on another thread, you will need to allocate something and it might as well be a `Task<T>`.

Answer (score 7):

Here you are:

```
public static async ValueTask ContinueWith<TResult>(this ValueTask<TResult> source,
    Action<ValueTask<TResult>> continuationAction)
{
    // The source task is consumed after the await, and cannot be used further.
    ValueTask<TResult> completed;
    try
    {
        completed = new(await source.ConfigureAwait(false));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.SetCanceled(oce.CancellationToken);
        completed = new(tcs.Task);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        completed = new(Task.FromException<TResult>(ex));
    }
    continuationAction(completed);
}
```

A simpler implementation would be to [`Preserve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1.preserve) the `ValueTask<TResult>` before the `await`, and then invoke the `continuationAction` passing the preserved task as argument. This would cause invariably an allocation though, even in the case of the successful completion of the task.

The reason that I am avoiding the one-line [`Task.FromCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromcanceled) method in the cancellation case, is because this method requires that the supplied `CancellationToken` is canceled, otherwise it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am posting it too late. However wanted to share the approach I used...

```
ValueTask<T> vt = ValueTaskTReturningMethod();
var awt = vt.GetAwaiter();
awt.OnCompleted(() => {
   T val = awt.GetResult();
   //code you want to execute after async operation completes
}
```

Comment: Or just `T val = await vt; // code you want to execute...` - much simpler